# (Date).ToString does not use specified delimiter

Tags: powershell

Why does the ToString() method return the date with '-' rather than the '/' specified.

```
PS 11:59  C:\src\t
>((Get-ChildItem 'u.txt').LastWriteTime).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')
2019-08-09
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/` is the [format specifier for a date separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator), which for your culture evidently is `-`.

As that documentation section notes...

> To change the date separator for a particular date and time string, specify the separator character within a literal string delimiter.

...which you would do like this...

```
((Get-ChildItem 'u.txt').LastWriteTime).ToString('yyyy''/''MM''/''dd')
```

...or this...

```
((Get-ChildItem 'u.txt').LastWriteTime).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd")
```

You can also [escape the `/` character](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#escape) to get the same result...

```
((Get-ChildItem 'u.txt').LastWriteTime).ToString('yyyy\/MM\/dd')
```

Comment: Thanks. One would think this could be more straightforward. Not very intuitive.

Comment: Well, it's about as straightforward as the year and day specifiers being lowercase but month specifiers are uppercase, and as straightforward as any other environment that uses ``\`` for escape sequences.  There's got to be _some_ way to tell it "insert the culture-specific date separator here", and `/` happens to be it.  Note that the same issue can present itself with the [time separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#timeSeparator) if you want a literal colon in your output.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'm not sure what you mean by "your configured short date string".  The `d` format will use the culture-specific date separator, which on the author's system is `-` whereas they want `/`.  Or do you mean after modifying the current culture's short date string (e.g. `(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'yyyy\/MM\/dd'`)?  In that case, `(Get-Date).ToShortDateString()` works as well.